# How to get points/path around the curves of a track

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, dynamic, coordinates, kinematics

I have a path that consists of points as shown in the figure below. Consider that as the center line of the track (curved track same as water slide in Unity3D). Now I want to generate the second set of points that takes the drag along the edges(green color line in 3-Dimensional coordinates). Can you help me out with the logic?

[image: Visualization]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you be more specific how this green line is defined?

Comment: The Green line is path of an object sliding on the path with out no friction. So, I wanted to define the new path of points with green line kind of turnings(sliding) at the corners,or when there is a turn of angle 'theta' along the turns.